# Why i'm getting more records while using inner join MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have table a with records and

```
       c1
| 1    1
| 2    1
| 3    1
| 4    1
```

Table b with records

```
      c3
| 1    1
| 2    1
```

while running this code
select * from a
inner join b on a.c1=b.c3;

I'm getting output

```
       c1   c3
| 1    1     1
| 2    1     1
| 3    1     1
| 4    1     1
| 5    1     1
| 6    1     1
| 7    1     1
| 8    1     1
```

Kindly anyone suggest how it works because this should only return 6 rows but returning 8 why ?

Comment: You have 4 records in a with c1 =1 and 2 in b with c3 =1 , 4 * 2 = 8.. To get 6 you would need a union rather than a join based on the published data